MODX toolbar disappeared after VersionX upgrade to 3.1
I upgraded the VersionX extra from 2.4 to 3.1. After that, the toolbar in Manager disappeared and there was the following error in the Javascript console:

I use MODX 3.0.5. I tried the upgrade on two different sites and the same error occurred. Any idea how I could debug this more?
